# How does the '!' (cut) operator exactly work in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I'm learning Prolog and I'm having some difficulties to understand how this particular operator works. I've been told it's used to stop backtracking during recursivity, but I can't quite picture it. What would be an example in a non-declarative language like Java? Maybe if I find a parallel I'm used to I'll be able to understand it.

Thank you!

Comment: It has nothing to do with recursivity. And in Java, there is no backtracking-search. See [tag:prolog-cut] for more.

Answer (score 0):

The cut (`!/0`) doesn't "stop backtracking": it simply eliminates a ***choice point***. Consider something like this,

```
even_or_odd( X , even ) :- 0 =:= X mod 2 .
even_or_odd( _ , odd  ) .
```

For any *odd* integer, it has a single solution: `odd`. But for any *even* integer, it has two solutions: it will first identify as `even`, and on backtracking, identify as `odd`.

An integer's being even or odd is ***deterministic***: `4` is not going to be `even` on first evaluation, and then magically become `odd` on reevaluation.

So, we introduce a cut to eliminate the choice point(s)/alternative(s):

```
identify_even_or_odd( X , even ) :- 0 =:= X mod 2 , ! .
identify_even_or_odd( _ , odd  ) .
```

Now, having made the determination that `X` is even, the cut eliminates the choice point, and essentially "prunes" the search tree: backtracking into the cut causes the entire containing predicate to fail (and continue backtracking through the solution tree).